# sympy printed output: color a subexpression?

Tags: sympy, mathml

I understanding that sympy can output maths suitable for rendering: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html

I want to tweak this slightly: I want to change the color of a subexpression within a sympy expression, e.g. so certain symbols are red.

For a concrete example:

```
red_parts = sympy.var('x') ** 2 + sympy.var('y')
other_parts = sympy.var('x')
mathml(make_red(red_parts) + other_parts))
```

Is this in any way achievable?

I know that presentation mathml supports css... but sympy seems to output content-mathml which browsers don't seem to render at all well. Though I found some [xsl stylesheets that do](https://www.w3.org/Math/XSL/Overview-tech.html). I don't know if the latex output has a concept of color.

## A little context

I want to play games with previewing and highlight sections of sympy expressions as I type.

Comment: can you please provide a sample mathml xml file for the example you mentioned?